# ajax submit return error in server but working fine in localhost

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I having the problem when try to run in one of my staging server(MVC c#.net), but the same code work fine in my localhost and also development server.. it kind of weird and I been troubleshot for whole 2 days..Anyone please help. Will it caused by any windows patches and caused the ajax not working fine in server?

I get the error prompt when click on form submit, the error is syntax error: Expected '}'

```
  $('#frmSet').bind('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // <-- important    
        var errMsg = $("#ErrMsg").val();   
        if (errMsg == ""){
            $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                iframe: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                        alert(xhr.statusText);
                        alert(textStatus);
                        alert(error);
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#_acset").parent().html(data.content);         
        }
```

This is my form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActSet", "Acts", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "frmSet" }))
```

I checked on the database, ajax submit actually done all the update in my database, but when it return it prompt error.

Answer (score 0):

try specifying `url` option. PS. I posted as an answer for readability

```
 ajaxSubmit({
            iframe: true,
            url: "http://myhost.com/url",
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                    alert(xhr.statusText);
                    alert(textStatus);
                    alert(error);
            }
```

Comment: tested, still the same.

Comment: Is the url pointing to the same domain as it was originated. If not than you are running into CORS problem. Open Developer Tools in your browser and see for any errors

Comment: Also set `type: 'POST'`

Comment: HI, I checked on the database, ajax submit actually done all the update in my database, but when it return it prompt error. So I think it is not the url problem and post problem..

Comment: Can you put the breakpoint in success function and see what data has been recieved?

Comment: Weird thing is even the database side is update successfully but when it return it go to Error function there and not success function

Comment: Finally, I found the problem... is due to the dot net framework, currently I am using dotnet framework 4.0 after update to 4.5.1 everything solved...Thanks.!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the problem... is due to the dot net framework, currently I am using dotnet framework 4.0 after update to 4.5.1 everything solved...Thanks.!!!!